# Когда ставлю знак "*" то сразу выдает ошибку e0349

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string x, y, z, i;
    cin >> x >> y;
    z = x + y;
    string greeting = z;
    int greeting_size = greeting.size();
    i = z * to_string(greeting_size);
    cout << i;
}
```

Comment: А как это вы хотите *перемножить* две строки?... `z * to_string(greeting_size);`? Не предусмотрено такое в языке...

Comment: Да чёрт с этой ошибкой, почему Вы решили перемножать две строки, если это не предусмотрено в C++?

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < greating_size; i++)
{
    new_text += text;
}
```